# Solving paired ordinary differential equations to find the equations determining inertial motion in a fluid subject to the Coriolis effect

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I want to solve the paired ordinary differential equations:
$$
\frac{du}{dt} = 2\Omega v \sin\phi  \\
\frac{dv}{dt} = -2\Omega u \sin \phi
$$
The book* I am working from says the solutions are:$$
u = V_H\sin(2\Omega \sin \phi t) \\
v= V_H\cos(2\Omega \sin \phi t)
$$
where:
$u$ and $v$ represent horizontal velocities in the $x-$ and $y-$ planes respectively
$$\Omega ~\text{is the angular rotation of Earth}$$
$$\phi ~\text{is the latitude}$$
$$ t ~\text{is time}$$
$$V_H^2 = u^2 + v^2$$

I'd be very grateful if someone could demonstrate how to solve these differential equations.$$
\text{*Pond and Pickard, "Introductory Dynamical Oceanography", 1983, Second Edition, p.64}$$

Comment: have you verified by substitution?

Comment: where are the constants of integration in the solutions? You should have 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the following system of linear differential equation:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{Bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\Omega\sin(\theta)\\
-2\Omega\sin(\theta) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

The eigenvalues and their respective eigenvectors of the square matrice on the right hand side are $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta)$ and $v_{1,2}=\{\mp i\phantom{x}1\}^{T}$. Now we define:

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
m\\
n
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{Bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

We then have the following differential equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{Bmatrix}
m\\
n
\end{Bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{Bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{Bmatrix}\\
\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\Omega\sin(\theta)\\
-2\Omega\sin(\theta) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{Bmatrix}\\
\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\Omega\sin(\theta)\\
-2\Omega\sin(\theta) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
m\\
n
\end{Bmatrix}
\\
\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta) & 0\\
0 & -i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
m\\
n
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Notice that this is simply two separate first order differential equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dm}{dt}&=\phantom{-}i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta)\phantom{x}m\\
\frac{dn}{dt}&=-i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta)\phantom{x}n\\
\\
m&=k_{m}\exp\left(\phantom{-}i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta)\phantom{.}t\right)\\
n&=k_{n}\exp\left(-i\phantom{.}2\Omega\sin(\theta)\phantom{.}t\right)
\end{align}
$$

Now we solve for $u$ and $v$ to obtain the result you want. I leave the rest to you.

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{Bmatrix}
u\\
v
\end{Bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
m\\
n
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please note that since I did not really understand what $\theta$ is in this problem I just assume it is constant.

Comment: Thanks Reza, that is incredibly helpful.